# is there a way to nest {{}} expressions in Laravel template?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a resource route generated by Artisan command as

```
Route::resource('posts','PostsController');
```

the URI of this route is posts/{post}/edit which require a dynamic value in the middle. But because I'm using the url() method to link all of my routs I am forced to nest the template expression as:

```
<a href="{{url('/posts/{{$show->id}}/edit')}}" class="btn btn-sm">Edit</a>
```

This is giving me an error: NotFoundHttpException because it couldn't get the {{$show->id}} part. How can I fix this?

Comment: At first sight you don't need the double {{ }} inside. Do just a single {}. Then another thing would be the single quotes enclosing the string param, I'd consider using double quotes. There's a question that suggests that below.

Answer (score 0):

In `PostsController`, create a new variable that you want to show up in the template. You should be able to use the `url()` function within a controller. (See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/urls)) Pass this value to the template like you normally would.

Just in case: [documentation on how to pass values to a template](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#displaying-data)

Comment: How about my route uri? it expects me to pass /posts/??/edit

Answer (score 0):

Use `<a href="<?php echo url('/posts/'.$show->id.'/edit')?>" class="btn btn-sm">Edit</a>` with out the use of `{{}}` notation.

Answer (score 0):

You need double quote and remove one bracket

Do you looking for something like this?

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
<a href="{{url("/posts/{$post->id}/edit")}}" class="btn btn-sm">Edit</a>
@endforeach
```